# "Icon" (ISOTYPE) charts in R shiny with Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, plot, statistics, shiny

I'm working on a project to build several models for data analysis and reporting using R and the amazing Shiny framework for web development. I'm getting started with R and Shiny but I've had an amazing experience so far, yet, I'd like to get some help in case someone has had experience with something similar to the kind of thing that I need for my project.

I'm looking to visualize some data in the form of an "icon chart", which from research online I've found are called "ISOTYPE" charts, the main idea being that data is represented as a stacked series of pictograms, where each one has a certain numeric meaning, for example

147 = ☻☻☻☻☻☻☻○○○○○○○

(Say for example that each ☻ figure means "a set of 20" and each ○ means "a single one", so that's why you only get 7 icons on the right to visualize the value of the variable since it currently sits at 147)

I found a blog of a person dedicated to building similar visualizations for data, but it seems that's in hiatus.

http://interactive-isotype.org/

Also, an idea I'm coming up with is to use some Font-awesome icons and write a function that displays what I need in the form of clusters of Icons from that library... yet, has anyone else had success with a situation like this before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question since, after all, I have found some resources that fit my use case and they seem viable for development. Hopefully it'll come in handy for the comunity later down the road :)

After further investigation, I found the name of "pictogram charts" as an alternative way to refer to this kind of data visualization.

To create pictograms easily, a function called pictograph() has been published by an author from the wonderful R-bloggers:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/easy-pictograms-using-r/

https://github.com/robertgrant/pictogram